# Two different queries on stimulsoft if variables are filled or not

Tags: mysql, sql, stimulsoft

I'm using the Stimulsoft Design to make reports and I'm using two variables to filter.

So I want to make the datasource to build one SQL statement if filter one is filled and the other is empty and another SQL if filter two is filled and the other is empty, and maybe an else statement...

So it would be something like this:

If filter one is filled and filter two is empty, then make SELECT 1, which is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableExample WHERE column1 LIKE '%{filter1}%'
```

If filter two is filled and filter one is empty, then make SELECT 2, which is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableExample WHERE id = '%{filter2}%'
```

and ID is a primary key.

Well, can I do that?

Maybe I could check it only using SQL, but I can't figure out how to do this,  could someone help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for a single query here?

Comment: Yes. Either if you know how to use stimulsoft and could teach me how to make two queries depending on the user input or maybe an easier way to solve this, which would be merging these two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a single query which contains your logic you could try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableExample
WHERE
    (COALESCE(filter2, '') = '' AND COALESCE(filter1, '') <> '' AND
     filter1 LIKE '%{filter1}%') OR
    (COALESCE(filter1, '') = '' AND COALESCE(filter2, '') <> '' AND
     id = '%{filter2}%')
```

Note, the somewhat ugly `COALESCE` calls are there because I don't know what you mean by `empty`.  Does this mean `NULL`, empty string, or both?

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.